# PHP Currency Regular Expression

Tags: php, regex, format, numbers

I am trying to find a piece of regex to match a currency value.

I would like to match only numbers and 1 decimal point ie

**Allowed**

- 10
- 100
- 100.00

**Not Allowed**

- Alpha Characters
- 100,00
- +/- 100

I have search and tried quite a few without any luck.

Hope you can advise

Comment: Note that the comma is the vali character in a lot of country's for decimal places. This software will not pass the turkey test like this. http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001075.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
if (preg_match('/^[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?$/', $subject))
{
    # Successful match
}
else
{
    # Match attempt failed
}
```

**Side note** : If you want to restrict how many decimal places you want, you can do something like this :

```
/^[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]{1,3})?$/im
```

So

```
100.000
```

will match, whereas

```
100.0001
```

wont.

If you need any further help, post a comment.

**PS** If you can, use the number formatter posted above. Native functions are always better (and faster), otherwise this solution will serve you well.

Comment: Thanks for bringing this to my attention. Fixed.

Comment: Any reason for the down voting? If you see a genuine problem I'd be happy to tweak the answer. However, down voting without saying anything is just being silly especially when it's the accepted answer.

Comment: This would still match `00000`, `0.1` and `0.123`. And besides the leading zeros, I don’t think Lee wanted a variable number of digits after the decimal point.

Comment: @ThePixelDeveloper: why did you add `i` (case insesitive) and `m` (multiline) flag? Arent't these useless? You are looking only for digits that are never case sensitive, you ar looking only in one line.

Comment: Totally correct @MarcoDemaio. The original post was created 4 years ago and I guess I did things blindly back then. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

How about this

```
if (preg_match('/^\d+(\.\d{2})?$/', $subject))
{
   // correct currency format
} else {
  //invalid currency format
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You might want to consider other alternatives to using a regex.

For example, there's the [`NumberFormatter`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.numberformatter.php) class, which provides flexible number and currency [parsing](http://php.net/manual/en/numberformatter.parsecurrency.php) and [formatting](http://php.net/manual/en/numberformatter.format.php), with build in internationalisation support.

It's built into PHP 5.3 and later, and is available as an extension on earlier versions of PHP 5.

Answer (score 0):

Try this regular expression:

```
^(?:[1-9]\d+|\d)(?:\.\d\d)?$
```

Comment: I tried this.

return (preg_match('^(?:[1-9]\d+|\d)(?:\.\d\d)?$', $vale)) ? TRUE : FALSE;

And just get error 

Message: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: No ending delimiter '^' found. Adding it everything passes.

Comment: preg_match('/^(?:[1-9]\d+|\d)(?:\.\d\d)?$/')

Comment: The `preg_*` functions use PCRE that need to be surrounded by delimiters. See http://docs.php.net/manual/en/intro.pcre.php

Comment: Still allowing invalid characters.

return (preg_match('/^(?:[1-9]\d+|\d)(?:\.\d\d)?$/', $this->price) )? TRUE : FALSE;

allows any Alpha character

Comment: @Lee: you should test the expression in a simple script (unit test for example): it should work as expected. I don't see how it would allow alpha chars.
Actually, it doesn't (I just tested it).